# JSViews observable array not refreshing

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

Apologies for another question on JSViews. I really love this system, but I am struggling occasionally.

I have a simple template which only needs to update which items in the array to show on select box change:

However, when I change the data "isSelected" the template is not being updated with the following:

ie:

```
function someClickFunction(sel) {
    value = sel.value;
    ....
    la_configure_list[0].isSelected = false;
    $.observable(la_configure_list).refresh(
            la_configure_list.slice(0)
        );
}
```

if I change it to

```
$.observable(la_configure_list).refresh(
        JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(la_configure_list))
                       );
```

it updates just fine.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
<script id="la-config-overview-list-template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {^{if isSelected}}
    <div class="col s12 la_review_list_item" data-index="{{:#index}}">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content" style="padding: 10px;">
                <div class="col s12 m6 l5 xl5">
                    <h6 style="font-weight: 700;" class="">{{:title}}</h6>
                        <div>Categories:</div>
                        <div>
                            {{for categories}}
                            <span class="chip">{{:#data}}</span>
                            {{/for}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
```

my html is

```
<div id="teacher_la_review_overview_main_wrapper" class="container body-content">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

the array is:

```
la_configure_list = [
{
    isSelected:true,
    title: "Title",
    categories: ["1", "2"....]
},
....
]
```

I set up the template:

```
$.templates("#la-config-overview-list-template").link("#la_review_list_overview_list_wrapper .row", la_configure_list);
```

I tried using $.view(elem).refresh(), but as my click action to update isSelected is outside the template, I cannot find the correct "elem" to use.

EDIT - Added actual update code:

```
function CategoryUpdate(sel) {

        var catSelected = sel.value;
        var catText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

        if (catSelected !== "-1") {
            for (var cs = 0; cs < la_configure_list.length; cs++) {
                if (la_configure_list[cs].categories == null) {
                    la_configure_list[cs].isSelected = false;
                    continue;
                }
                var categories = la_configure_list[cs].categories;
                var isFound = false;
                for (var c = 0; c < categories.length; c++) {
                    var category = categories[c];
                    if (category === catText) {

                        la_configure_list[cs].isSelected = true;
                        isFound = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!isFound) {
                    la_configure_list[cs].isSelected = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var x = 0; x < la_configure_list.length; x++) {
                la_configure_list[x].isSelected = true;
            }
        }

        $.observable(la_configure_list).refresh(
            JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(la_configure_list))
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array `la_configure_list.slice(0)` is a shallow copy of `la_configure_list`. The observable array `refresh()` method is used for array updates – sorting, removing or adding items. It is optimized to avoid unnecessary updates. In fact it analyses the array and triggers move, insert and remove events for any changes it detects.

In your case although you copied the array, it is a shallow copy, so the array items are the same, and the order is unchanged. Therefore no observable array change event is triggered. When you use `JSON.parse` etc you are replacing the object by cloned copies, so now `refresh()` considers that all the items have been removed and then new ones added.

But why don't you make any change to the `isSelected` properties observable, along the lines of:

```
function someClickFunction(sel) {
    value = sel.value;
    ...
    $.observable(la_configure_list[index]).propertyChange("isSelected", false);
    ...
}
```

Since you have observable data-linking `{^{if isSelected}}` you should not need to do any additional refreshing of either the array or the views…

Comment: thanks for this, I inderstand better. The reason I am not doing it as a property change is that I am actually trasversing the category array and looking to see if a selected category is in the list and updating isSelected on each array item. So every item in the arrat has isSelected set to true or false based on a search condition. Would it not be slow to update each one individually observably, rather than one update at the end? You say refresh is used for sorting, but that is what I am trying to do. Is there a better way?

Comment: I edited my question with the full code for update/sort

Comment: You can use observable().propertyChange() on each item as long as you don't switch the same item backwards and forwards redundantly. So just hit each item once with a propertyChange(). Setting propertyChange(..., false) if the value is already false will not trigger an event, nor setting to true if already true, so that is OK. So it should be a reasonable approach to visit each item once...